# System failure after changing cache battery on IBM power5 machine

Tags: raid, cache, boot, ibm, battery

As the title states, I got a used IBM power5 9405-series machine, and after changing the cache battery, the system refuses to boot up. I only see a blank screen on the console.

What could be the problem and How to diagnose it?